# Does s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject mean one version was lost, or the whole object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a configuration for a S3 bucket where objects are stored as Reduced Redundancy Storage and versioning is enabled. I want to trigger a lambda function on the `s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject` event so I can recreate the object, but I am unsure whether this event means that the whole object was lost, or just one version. My assumption is that it is just one version, but I haven't been able to find confirmation in the documentation or elsewhere, and I don't know if there is a way to adequately test it.

Comment: FYI you generally should not use Reduced Redundancy Storage any more. It costs more than S3 Standard and S3 Infrequent Access.

Comment: @jarmod that's usually true, but not everywhere.  RRS is still notably lower than standard in some higher cost regions, like São Paulo, and slightly lower in others, like Singapore.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject` event is triggered when Amazon S3 detects that it has lost all replicas of an object and can no longer service requests for that object.

Note: AWS S3 Reduced Redundancy cost recently became higher than Standard Storage which makes using Reduced Redundancy unreasonable.

e.g In US East N. Virginia

- Standard Storage : $0.023 per GB (First 50 TB / month)
- Reduced Redundancy Storage : $0.0240 per GB (First 1 TB / month) and $0.0236 per GB (Next 49 TB / month)

Compare the price of [Standard Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) & [Reduced Redundancy Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/reduced-redundancy/).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize the pricing had changed. I don't see why anyone would use Reduced Redundancy in that case, except for maybe in those few regions where it is still a bit cheaper.

Comment: It seems like RRS going to die sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

As per [AWS Documentation :](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html)

*You might want to enable versioning to protect yourself from unintended overwrites and deletions or to archive objects so that you can retrieve previous versions of them.*

and

*This functionality prevents you from accidentally overwriting or deleting objects and affords you the opportunity to retrieve a previous version of an object.*

Object Versioning Is Common across S3 thus inherently it would follow this , thus I think that the loss of object would of that version only.